# Track program change on WAGO PLC with CoDeSys

Tags: codesys

I need to increment an integer value each time the PLC program is updated to track changes.

There are system events like `online_change` and `before_download`, but I have no idea how to implement their functions.

Also I need to save value between updates. I think the tracking variable should be created as `RETAIN` but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable declaration type should be `VAR RETAIN PERSISTENT` in your case. Variables declared under `RETAIN` only will lose their values (intentionally) with a program change.

I believe the builtin Codesys library **SysLibProjectInfo.lib** has what you are looking for with the function **SysGetProjectID**. If you store SysGetProjectID as a `RETAIN PERSISTENT` and then compare against it, you can track changes (or, this unique value may be exactly what you wanted in the first place, without manually creating an ID).

Note: Depending on how you declare your variables, changing the I/O configuration can have unexpected changes even on `VAR RETAIN PERSISTENT` variables (as all dynamically allocated addresses are shifted and may not point where they used to).

Comment: @BatRamboZPM If you found a different way, would you mind posting your own answer for reference please.

Comment: Your answer points to the right solution. I used similar implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you you only want to know like what version is running on the PLC and you want to track changes that you make? You can do it two ways:

Since it's a constant each time you make a change external to the PLC you roll the rev of a variable that is declared like SoftwareVersion :WORD := 100; and keep it in a Revision global list that you can add your notes to and change the version before downloading to PLC.
You can also use the PLC summary area that has fields to enter the values and then you can read them through CoDeSys without software upload.

And of course the suggestion above can work.